# WPF- Horizontal and Vertical position of a Run Element in a FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

Is there anyway to get the horizontal position(pixel) and vertical position(pixel) of a Run element in a FlowDocument?

Edit:
All i need to do is scroll to that position and make it the top line of the FlowDocument.

Comment: Only a comment but if you need that level of control a FixedDocument may be better.  Why do you need the position?

Comment: [`GetCharacterRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.getcharacterrect.aspx) could help if document is inside `RichTextBox`.

Comment: @Blam: All I need is just to scroll to that position. And make it the top line of the current FlowDocument...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To Answer Your Question**
The code needed to get the position of a content element in a document is all internal to .NET and not publically exposed. You would need access to an [IContentHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.icontenthost.aspx) implementation, which the built-in document viewers do not publically expose. So, there is no supported way to do what you are asking.

**To Solve Your Actual Problem**
There is a way to achieve your desired result of scrolling the element to the top of the view. What you want to do is scroll to the end of the document, then call [BringIntoView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkcontentelement.bringintoview.aspx) on the element you want to have at the top.

There are [multiple ways a FlowDocument can be displayed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx#flow_document_types) in an application. How you handle the scrolling depends on which control you are using to present the `FlowDocument`.

- In a `RichTextBox`, use the [ScrollToEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend.aspx) method.
- In a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`, you will need to get its internal ScrollViewer and call [ScrollToBottom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltobottom.aspx) on it. (You have to wait until the control is loaded before you can get a template part from it.)

  ```
  private void MyControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      mScrollViewer = mViewer.Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", mViewer) as ScrollViewer;
  }
  ```
- In a `FlowDocumentReader`, the process is a bit more complex.

  1. When the control is loaded, register for changes to the ViewingMode property and run the handler once to account for the starting value:

     ```
     private void MyControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(FlowDocumentReader.ViewingModeProperty, typeof(FlowDocumentReader));
         descriptor.AddValueChanged(mReader, (s, a) => Reader_ViewModeChanged());
         Reader_ViewModeChanged();
     }
     ```
  2. In the handler, dig in to find the `ScrollViewer`. It will only be present when the `ViewingMode` is set to `Scroll`:

     ```
     private void Reader_ViewModeChanged()
     {
         mScrollViewer = null;
         if (mReader.ViewingMode == FlowDocumentReaderViewingMode.Scroll)
         {
             var contentHost = mReader.Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", mReader) as DependencyObject;
             if (contentHost != null && VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(contentHost) > 0)
             {
                 var documentScrollViewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contentHost, 0) as FlowDocumentScrollViewer;
                 if (documentScrollViewer != null)
                 {
                     documentScrollViewer.ApplyTemplate();
                     mScrollViewer = documentScrollViewer.Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", documentScrollViewer) as ScrollViewer;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     ```
  3. Once you have the `ScrollViewer`, you can call [ScrollToBottom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltobottom.aspx) on it when desired.

Now, scroll to the bottom of the document, then call [BringIntoView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkcontentelement.bringintoview.aspx) on your `Run`, and it should be at the top of the view.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm using a richtext box... so things are very easy :) thanks a lot..... Previously I tried  BringIntoView without ScrolllToEnd,  and failed.

Answer (score 1):

Does not bring it to the top but just call [BringIntoView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598110(v=vs.110).aspx) on the Run.  Save a reference to the Run.

Answer (score 0):

It may be late but i still want to share the way i DID it in WPF.
You need an offset to do so.

As the above said: Flow gave you:

```
flow.ScrollToHome(); // Bottom
```

But also gave: `ScrollToVerticalOffset (get from Rect)`

if you have index (offset of the char/line) - you can find it in you saved data or get the TextPointer with `flow.Selection.Start/End`

```
TextPointer t_st = flow.Selection.Start;
double offset = flow.Document.ContentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(t_st);

    private void gotoOffset(double offset)
    {
        TextPointer myTextPointer1 = flow.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset((int)offset);
        flow.Selection.Select(myTextPointer1, myTextPointer1);
        flow.Focus();
        Rect screenPos2 = myTextPointer1.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        double offset2 = screenPos2.Top;
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        flow.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset2);
        flow.Focus();
    }
```

As the code above, We get the Rect from TextPointer, the Textpointer and get from Offset.
The focus just to make sure to place the cursor in right place.

Sometime the issue happen when you jump to many offset.
I recomment to trigger `flow.ScrollToHome();` Before jump (because this ScrollToVerticalOffset true from the start, not any line)